# Send total ether balance using geth/web3js

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I installed a full node and synced to rinkeby testnet. I created 3 accounts using

```
eth.personal.newAccount
```

Assumed the balances of 3 accounts

- Account A: 1 eth (this is coinbase account)
- Account B: 1 eth
- Account C: 1 eth

What i want is sending 2 eth to Account D at one time to reduce the fee?

Is it possible using geth or web3js API?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send from multiple accounts in one transaction.
In order to send 2 eth to account D you should create 2 transaction from account A and account B(or account C).